# How do I make an API call inside a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Firebase Cloud Function where I make an API call to NewsAPI and retrieve a set of articles. The code below is an example, and it aims to retrieve articles from BBCNews.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var url = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?' +
  'sources=bbc-news&' +
  'apiKey={myKey}';

const GetArticles = () => (
  fetch(new Request(url))
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
);
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Kesav\Coding stuff\project-academy\functions\index.js:9:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at C:\Users\kkosa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:661:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\kkosa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:5:58)
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: The error is giving you the answer, Request is not defined, try using the URL directly, just make sure myKey is replaced by the right value... Lastly, be aware your need to use the Blaze plan to use outbound queries

Answer (score 0):

You apparen't don't have any code that imports `Request`.  That's not a "free object" in nodejs.  You're going to have to find an HTTP client library for node ([you have many options](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143)), import it, and use that in your code.